# eliminating embedded actions from antlr4 grammar

Tags: antlr4

I have an antlr grammar in which embedded actions are used to collect data bottom up and build aggregated data structures. A short version is given below, where the aggregated data structures are only printed (ie no classes are created for them in this short sample code).

```
grammar Sample;
top returns [ArrayList l]
    @init { $l = new ArrayList<String>(); }
    : (mid { $l.add($mid.s); } )* ;
mid returns [String s]
    : i1=identifier 'hello' i2=identifier
        { $s = $i1.s + " bye " + $i2.s; }
    ;
identifier returns [String s]
    : ID { $s = $ID.getText(); } ;
ID  : [a-z]+ ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Its corresponding Main program is:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
    SampleLexer lexer = new SampleLexer( new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream( lexer );
    SampleParser parser = new SampleParser( tokens );
    ArrayList<String> top = parser.top().l;
    System.out.println(top);
  }
}
```

And a sample test is:

```
aaa hello bbb
xyz hello pqr
```

Since one of the objectives of antlr is to keep the grammar file reusable and action-independent, I am trying to delete the actions from this file and move it to a tree walker. I took a first stab at it with the following code:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
    SampleLexer lexer = new SampleLexer( new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream( lexer );
    SampleParser parser = new SampleParser( tokens );
    ParseTree tree = parser.top();
    ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
    walker.walk( new Walker(), tree );
  }
}
public class Walker extends SampleBaseListener {
  public void exitTop(SampleParser.TopContext ctx ) {
    System.out.println( "Exit Top : " + ctx.mid() );
  }
  public String exitMid(SampleParser.MidContext ctx ) {
    return ctx.identifier() + " bye "; // ignoring the 2nd instance here
  }
  public String exitIdentifier(SampleParser.IdentifierContext ctx ) {
    return ctx.ID().getText() ;
  }
}
```

But obviously this is wrong, because at the least, the return types of the Walker methods should be void, so they dont have a way to return aggregated values upstream. Secondly, I dont see a way how to access the "i1" and "i2" from the walker code, so I am not able to differentiate between the two instances of "identifier" in that rule.

Any suggestions on how to separate the actions from the grammar for this purpose?

Should I use a visitor instead of a listener here, since the visitor has the capability of returning values? If I use a visitor, how do I solve the problem of differentiating between "i1" and "i2" (as mentioned above)?

Does a visitor perform its action only at the exit of a rule (unlike the listeners, which exist for both entry and exit)? For example, if I have to initialize the list at the entry of rule "top", how can I do it with a visitor, which executes only at the conclusion of a rule? Do I need a enterTop listener for that purpose?

*EDIT:* After the initial post, I have modified the rule "top" to create and return a list, and pass this list back to the main program for printing. This is to illustrate why I need an initialization mechanism for the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what you are trying to do I think you may benefit from using ANTLR's BaseVisitor Class rather than the BaseListener Class.

Assuming your grammar is this (I generalized it and I'll explain the changes below):

```
grammar Sample;

top : mid* ;
mid : i1=identifier 'hello' i2=identifier ;
identifier : ID ;

ID  : [a-z]+ ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Then your Walker would look like this:

```
public class Walker extends SampleBaseVisitor<Object> {
    public ArrayList<String> visitTop(SampleParser.TopContext ctx) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (SampleParser.MidContext midCtx : ctx.mid()) {
            arrayList.add(visitMid(midCtx));
        }

        return arrayList;
    }

    public String visitMid(SampleParser.MidContext ctx) {
        return visitIdentifier(ctx.i1) + " bye " + visitIdentifier(ctx.i2);
    }

    public String visitIdentifier(SampleParser.IdentifierContext ctx) {
        return ctx.getText();
    }
}
```

This allows you to visit and get the result of any rule you want.

You are able to access `i1` and `i2`, as you labeled them through the visitor methods. Note that you don't really need the `identifier` rule since it contains only one token and you can access a token's text directly in the `visitMid`, but really it's personal preference.

You should also note that `SampleBaseVisitor` is a generic class, where the generic parameter determines the return type of the visit methods. For your example I set the generic parameter `Object`, but you could even make your own class which contains the information you want to preserve and use that for your generic parameter.

Here are some more useful [methods](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/AbstractParseTreeVisitor.html) which `BaseVisitor` inherits which may help you out.

Lastly, your main method would end up looking something like this:

```
public static void main( String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    SampleLexer lexer = new SampleLexer(CharStreams.fromStream(fileInputStream));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    SampleParser parser = new SampleParser(tokens);

    for (String string : new Walker().visitTop(parser.top())) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

As a side note, the `ANTLRFileStream` class is [deprecated](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRFileStream.html) in ANTLR4.
It is recommend to use `CharStreams` instead.

Comment: Tomer: Great answer! Just one question remaining, how to move the initialization also to the visitor code? To illustrate this problem, I have modified the rule "top" to make and return a list. Since visitor is executed only at the end of a rule, how can I make it do the initialization? Can you update your answer for this also? Then I will accept your answer.

Comment: The antlr book also talks about "annotating parse trees", but I am not sure how to do it when different rules have got different return types. The book's example only talks about return value of int for all the rules. If anybody can suggest the annotation technique for the above grammar, that will also be a big help.

Comment: I have changed my answer, note that the visitor's generic parameter is now `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

As Terence Parr points out in the Definitive Reference, one main difference between Visitor and Listener is that the Visitor can return values.  And that can be convenient.  But Listener has a place too!  [What I do for listener is exemplified in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180073/parse-and-return-a-list-of-doubles-using-antlr4/45180087#45180087).  Granted, there are simpler ways of parsing a list of numbers, but I made that answer to show a **complete and working example of how to aggregate return values from a listener into a public data structure that can be consumed later**.

```
public class ValuesListener : ValuesBaseListener
{
    public List<double> doubles = new List<double>(); // <<=== SEE HERE
    public override void ExitNumber(ValuesParser.NumberContext context)
    {
        doubles.Add(Convert.ToDouble(context.GetChild(0).GetText()));
    }
}
```

Looking closely at the Listener class, I include a public data collection -- a `List<double>` in this case -- to collect values parsed or calculated in the listener events.  You can use any data structure you like: another custom class, a list, a queue, a stack (**great** for calculations and expression evaluation), whatever you like.

So while the Visitor is arguably more flexible, the Listener is a strong contender too, depending on how you want to aggregate your results.

Comment: So in effect, you are managing the return values through global variables, one global variable per rule?

Comment: Also, the rule number might be called somewhere else in the parse tree, so you will have to initialize its global variable inside EnterNumber() listener, and not in the global section.

Comment: Not exactly, no.  In the example above, I'm storing the results of my interaction with the various listener rules in a `List<double>`.  Other times I might save results in a stack or even a custom static class.